# Comparing overall and conditional models

Tags: regression, predictive-models, r-squared, rms

Let's say I have two regression models with 5 variables, one that is for all observations, and one that only includes values when the temperature is higher than 75 degrees. As an example I have this:

This is the overall model with obviously more observations:

*RMSE* = 2664.02

*RSQ* = 0.82286

This is the conditional model:

*RMSE*  = 2510.09

*RSQ* = 0.69594

Which model would I choose? One has a smaller R but smaller RMSE? Is the conditional just always better for that condition than the overall one ? Shouldn't the conditional be more accurate as it only takes the values that apply to the model ? Or is the overall stronger because it takes more observations ?

Comment: is temperature one of the five variables?

Comment: Yes it is. But it is also a condition